# Atom.io with Nuclide : Line marker

Tags: atom-editor, nuclide-editor

Before I reset my mac, While using Atom ( with nuclide plugin installed ) I was able to mark lines. ( clicking on left side of line numbers ).

After resetting my mac and installing Atom, I can't find that option. I also tried many Atom plugins but I couldn't find it. Please see the screenshot attached bellow ( I've putted dots on image to show what was it look like ).

[image]

Do you know the option / plugin name?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the `Nuclide` plugin and it's a `Breakpoint`. It's found in the `nuclide-debugger` feature.

For this to work, make sure the `nuclide-debugger` feature is active in `Nuclide`'s config (`Settings` » `Packages` » `Nuclide`):

[image]

To add a `breakpoint` to a line, click the `gutter` (as you tried), or press <kbd>F9</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Too late answer but still useful.

install: atom-ide-ui

[image]

[image]